# facebook.com available_versions API doesn't return 7.14.0 yet

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

7.14.0 is the latest Facebook Unity SDK but the facebook.com available_versions API doesn't list it.

Facebook, please fix.

https://www.facebook.com/unitysdk/available_versions?unity_version=2017.4.14f1

Answer (score 0):

This URL now returns 7.14.0, but the automatic updater is still broken.

Every time you do a build or start the project up, you will get this:

```
SDKUpdater failed: stdout:
[UpdateSupportedSDKList] Download https://www.facebook.com/unitysdk/available_versions?unity_version=2017.4.14f1
[UpdateSupportedSDKList] Received <{
"versions": [
"7.9.4",
"7.10.1",
"7.12.2",
"7.13.0",
"7.14.0"
]
}> to <C:\ProgramData\Unity/Facebook\SupportedSDKVersions\2017.4.14f1>
[UpdateAvailableSDKs] Download https://www.facebook.com/unitysdk/download?sdk_version=7.14.0 to C:\Users\taylor\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6313.tmp
ValidateSDK D:\Program Files\Unity2017\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\Facebook\SDK\7.9.4 - C:\Users\taylor\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6313.tmp_unzipped
stderr:
Unhandled sdkuploader error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\taylor\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6313.tmp_unzipped\ivy.xml'.
```

It downloads the latest Unity SDK, then unzips it, then looks for ivy.xml. But there is no ivy.xml. I have put in an additional FB bug report.